# UINavigationItem TitleView crash when a new view is pushed

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

In the view did load of a view controller, I customise the title view with an image:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigationBarCentralImage.png"]];
```

So far so good, it display the image in the center of the navigation bar. 
However, when I pop the current view and push a new view which is working well without the title view customisation, it crashes.
This is the code that I am using to pop/push

```
-(void)popLastViewAndPush:(id)viewController
{
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [SharedAppDelegate.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
    if([controllers objectAtIndex:[controllers count] -1] == viewController)
        return;

    [controllers removeLastObject];
    SharedAppDelegate.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;

    [SharedAppDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

I am a bit stuck and don't understand why it is actually crashing with the title view customisation

Comment: Does the crashing happen if you comment out the title view customization? ie: is that actually what's causing it?

Comment: yes if I comment the self.navigationItem.titleView line, no crash!
else what would be the actual point of this post?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using ARC, then change the line of code to:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"navigationBarCentralImage.png"]] autorelease];
```

Have to add an `autorelease` to the allocated object.